# Missing free space in new zfs raidz2 zpool?

Tags: freebsd, zfs

I'm running Nas4Free 10.2.0.2 - Prester (revision 1814) which is based on FreeBSD 10.2-RELEASE-p2 #0 r287260M: Fri Aug 28 18:38:18 CEST 2015. System has 24 GB memory. I've tried with `ashift=9` and 12 without difference.

I only get 14.7T of free space. Why is that?

**Edit**: I've now tried with OpenIndiana's ZFS implementation with same machine and it gives 28.5T free and lists drives as 8001.49GB. So this might be a bug in FreeBSD's ZFS implementation or FreeBSD HDD driver bug?

**Edit**: I've now tried with FreeBSD-10.2-STABLE-amd64-20150917-r287929-memstick.img and that gives 28.1T free space so it is a bug.

Disks:

```
ada0 at ata2 bus 0 scbus2 target 0 lun 0
ada0: <ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z AR13> ACS-2 ATA SATA 3.x device
ada0: 300.000MB/s transfers (SATA 2.x, UDMA5, PIO 8192bytes)
ada0: 7630885MB (15628053168 512 byte sectors: 16H 63S/T 16383C)
ada1 at ata2 bus 0 scbus2 target 1 lun 0
ada1: <ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z AR13> ACS-2 ATA SATA 3.x device
ada1: 300.000MB/s transfers (SATA 2.x, UDMA5, PIO 8192bytes)
ada1: 7630885MB (15628053168 512 byte sectors: 16H 63S/T 16383C)
ada2 at ata3 bus 0 scbus3 target 0 lun 0
ada2: <ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z AR13> ACS-2 ATA SATA 3.x device
ada2: 300.000MB/s transfers (SATA 2.x, UDMA5, PIO 8192bytes)
ada2: 7630885MB (15628053168 512 byte sectors: 16H 63S/T 16383C)
ada3 at ata3 bus 0 scbus3 target 1 lun 0
ada3: <ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z AR13> ACS-2 ATA SATA 3.x device
ada3: 300.000MB/s transfers (SATA 2.x, UDMA5, PIO 8192bytes)
ada3: 7630885MB (15628053168 512 byte sectors: 16H 63S/T 16383C)
ada4 at ata4 bus 0 scbus4 target 0 lun 0
ada4: <ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z AR13> ACS-2 ATA SATA 3.x device
ada4: 300.000MB/s transfers (SATA 2.x, UDMA5, PIO 8192bytes)
ada4: 7630885MB (15628053168 512 byte sectors: 16H 63S/T 16383C)
ada5 at ata5 bus 0 scbus5 target 0 lun 0
ada5: <ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z AR13> ACS-2 ATA SATA 3.x device
ada5: 300.000MB/s transfers (SATA 2.x, UDMA5, PIO 8192bytes)
ada5: 7630885MB (15628053168 512 byte sectors: 16H 63S/T 16383C)
```

Remove old attempt and ZFS metadata:

```
storage: /# zpool destroy storage2

storage: /# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/ada0 bs=1m count=128
storage: /# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/ada1 bs=1m count=128
storage: /# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/ada2 bs=1m count=128
storage: /# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/ada3 bs=1m count=128
storage: /# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/ada4 bs=1m count=128
storage: /# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/ada5 bs=1m count=128

storage: /# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/ada0 oseek=15628000000
storage: /# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/ada1 oseek=15628000000
storage: /# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/ada2 oseek=15628000000
storage: /# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/ada3 oseek=15628000000
storage: /# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/ada4 oseek=15628000000
storage: /# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/ada5 oseek=15628000000
```

Create new pool:

```
storage: /# zpool create storage2 raidz2 ada0 ada1 ada2 ada3 ada4 ada5
```

zfs list:

```
storage: /# zfs list
NAME       USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
storage2   432K  14.5T   192K  /storage2
```

iostat:

```
storage: /# zpool iostat storage2
               capacity     operations    bandwidth
pool        alloc   free   read  write   read  write
----------  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----
storage2     900K  43.5T      0      1      0  7.84K
```

zpool list:

```
storage: /# zpool list
NAME       SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
storage2  43.5T   900K  43.5T         -     0%     0%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
```

zpool status:

```
storage: /# zpool status
  pool: storage2
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        storage2    ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz2-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ada0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            ada1    ONLINE       0     0     0
            ada2    ONLINE       0     0     0
            ada3    ONLINE       0     0     0
            ada4    ONLINE       0     0     0
            ada5    ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

zfs list:

```
storage: /# zfs list -t all
NAME       USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
storage2   480K  14.5T   192K  /storage2
```

Properties:

```
# zfs get all storage2
NAME      PROPERTY              VALUE                  SOURCE
storage2  type                  filesystem             -
storage2  creation              Thu Sep 24 18:48 2015  -
storage2  used                  623K                   -
storage2  available             14.5T                  -
storage2  referenced            192K                   -
storage2  compressratio         1.00x                  -
storage2  mounted               yes                    -
storage2  quota                 none                   default
storage2  reservation           none                   default
storage2  recordsize            128K                   default
storage2  mountpoint            /storage2              default
storage2  sharenfs              off                    default
storage2  checksum              on                     default
storage2  compression           off                    default
storage2  atime                 on                     default
storage2  devices               on                     default
storage2  exec                  on                     default
storage2  setuid                on                     default
storage2  readonly              off                    default
storage2  jailed                off                    default
storage2  snapdir               hidden                 default
storage2  aclmode               discard                default
storage2  aclinherit            restricted             default
storage2  canmount              on                     default
storage2  xattr                 off                    temporary
storage2  copies                1                      default
storage2  version               5                      -
storage2  utf8only              off                    -
storage2  normalization         none                   -
storage2  casesensitivity       sensitive              -
storage2  vscan                 off                    default
storage2  nbmand                off                    default
storage2  sharesmb              off                    default
storage2  refquota              none                   default
storage2  refreservation        none                   default
storage2  primarycache          all                    default
storage2  secondarycache        all                    default
storage2  usedbysnapshots       0                      -
storage2  usedbydataset         192K                   -
storage2  usedbychildren        432K                   -
storage2  usedbyrefreservation  0                      -
storage2  logbias               latency                default
storage2  dedup                 off                    default
storage2  mlslabel                                     -
storage2  sync                  standard               default
storage2  refcompressratio      1.00x                  -
storage2  written               192K                   -
storage2  logicalused           80K                    -
storage2  logicalreferenced     9.50K                  -
storage2  volmode               default                default
storage2  filesystem_limit      none                   default
storage2  snapshot_limit        none                   default
storage2  filesystem_count      none                   default
storage2  snapshot_count        none                   default
storage2  redundant_metadata    all                    default
```

zdb -C

```
# zdb -C storage2

MOS Configuration:
        version: 5000
        name: 'storage2'
        state: 0
        txg: 4
        pool_guid: 9410028398282520009
        hostid: 1452759488
        hostname: 'storage.home'
        vdev_children: 1
        vdev_tree:
            type: 'root'
            id: 0
            guid: 9410028398282520009
            create_txg: 4
            children[0]:
                type: 'raidz'
                id: 0
                guid: 16070893740466238556
                nparity: 2
                metaslab_array: 34
                metaslab_shift: 38
                ashift: 12
                asize: 48009350479872
                is_log: 0
                create_txg: 4
                children[0]:
                    type: 'disk'
                    id: 0
                    guid: 17748612860167792044
                    path: '/dev/ada0'
                    phys_path: '/dev/ada0'
                    whole_disk: 1
                    create_txg: 4
                children[1]:
                    type: 'disk'
                    id: 1
                    guid: 13659584123500602452
                    path: '/dev/ada1'
                    phys_path: '/dev/ada1'
                    whole_disk: 1
                    create_txg: 4
                children[2]:
                    type: 'disk'
                    id: 2
                    guid: 16565608857540887077
                    path: '/dev/ada2'
                    phys_path: '/dev/ada2'
                    whole_disk: 1
                    create_txg: 4
                children[3]:
                    type: 'disk'
                    id: 3
                    guid: 400417648284480610
                    path: '/dev/ada3'
                    phys_path: '/dev/ada3'
                    whole_disk: 1
                    create_txg: 4
                children[4]:
                    type: 'disk'
                    id: 4
                    guid: 15293896650775132923
                    path: '/dev/ada4'
                    phys_path: '/dev/ada4'
                    whole_disk: 1
                    create_txg: 4
                children[5]:
                    type: 'disk'
                    id: 5
                    guid: 14105808749251955600
                    path: '/dev/ada5'
                    phys_path: '/dev/ada5'
                    whole_disk: 1
                    create_txg: 4
        features_for_read:
            com.delphix:hole_birth
            com.delphix:embedded_data
```

Comment: Please add `zpool list`, `zpool status` and `zfs list -t all`.

Comment: @drookie Now added.

Comment: No idea why you see any fs, didn't notice any zfs create commands

Comment: Point is - could it be you created a zfs on this pool beforehand, and didn't destroy it via `zfs destroy storage2` ?

Comment: @Dani_l I've always destroyed it and that's why there's those dd commands zeroing the first 128 MB of drives and last sectors. But it was created before system update because those drives were seen only as 2.x TB drives. So it's possible that there is still zfs metadata lurking around from the first try.

Comment: I suggest you write to freebsd-fs@ mailing list and describe this. I don't even understand how did you get 43.5T from 5 x 7.6Tb drives (yeah, I know they are 8T, but anyway). They will probably ask you to import that pool on a recent -STABLE.

Comment: if possible, show me `zdb | grep ashift`.

Comment: Can you show the output of `gpart show`, so we have a better idea of how you partitioned your disks for use in ZFS?

Comment: @Kassandry he's using dedicated disks, it's evident from `zpool create` and `zpool status`.